# find h files using iregex Bash

Tags: bash, find

I'm using this line to find h files using bash but when it does it also finds bash files because of the .sh ending and I'm not sure how i can limit the find to only find files with a .h not a . and some h as last character.

```
find . -iregex '.*\(h\)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use enhanced regex with anchor `$` to only match `.h`:

```
find . -iregex '.*\.h$'
```

Comment: Ok so I am actually looking for java and c files too but im not quite sure how to make it work i tried as you said something like this: find . -iregex '.*(\.java$|\.c$|\.h$)' but it wont work

Comment: For that you need to use extended regex in find. So this works in OSX: `find -E . -iregex '.*\.(h|java)$'`

Comment: On Linux you can use: `find -regextype posix-extended . -iregex '.*\.(h|java)$'` command

Answer (score 3):

What about the much simpler

```
find -iname '*.h'
```

This is better because it does only find files that end in `.h` and is maybe faster then using a full regex.

For regex the right approach is

```
find -iregex '\.h$'
```

the `\.` escapes the '.' so that it matches a '.'. And the `$` tells it it should be the last part in the match.

Added because of question in comment:

Normally

```
find \( -iname '*.h' -or -iname '*.c' \)
```

works fine for me. The `\( \)` is to escape the parenthesis from the shell.

Comment: How would i use -iname to find multiple file endings? I tried the -o as or but that is non existant here so I tried searching the internet but i couldn't find much help

Comment: @CuppleKay If my edit does not answer your question, make a new question or better search for `find` tutorials.

Comment: As I just told you I serached the internet but there was no -iname to find. If you could just tell me how I can search for .h and .c everything would go a little faster.

Comment: @CuppleKay Ever heard of [`man find` (link)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)?

Comment: yes and it doesn't work when i try it on MINGW Shell. this is a forum to help people solve their problems not to tell them to look else where even though you should be clever enough to know that they have indeed looked else where already

Comment: @CuppleKay You forgot to mention all those details in your question. What version of find and which "OS" it is. My MSYS provides `find --version` which says GNU 4.4.2. And i just tested and it works wtih that version. You are asking people for help. Don't scoff them if you are not phrasing the right questions.

Comment: How should I know that I'm not phrasing the right question if no one tells me. No one would do that on purpose